# Share storage between a sub vector and a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

In R, one can create a matrix from a (whole) vector by using `matrix` or adding a `dim` attribute to the vector (`dim(x)=c(2,2)` for example). But as soon as the vector of the new matrix is modified, a copy is made and the matrix uses its own storage.

My problem is the following: I need to manage a list of matrices, of different dimensions, which, I interpret in my algorithm, either as a list of matrices or as a vector long vector made of all the matrices. The tranformation between a long vector and list and a list of matrices is using too much CPU time for what it is.

Is it possible to force a matrix to share its internal representation (its array) with a vector, such that if I modify the `matrix` or the `vector`, the modification is seen by the other object too.

Example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- matrix(x[2:4],2,2)
y[1,1] <- 1234

print(x)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

print(y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1234    3
[2,]    2    4
```

What I want, assuming there exists a *`matrix.by.reference`* function which would implement my question above:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- matrix.by.reference(x[1:4],2,2)
y[1,1] <- 1234

print(x)
[1]  1234  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

print(y)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1234    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `array` rather than a list of matrices? You can use single index notation as if it were still a vector, but still pull out the matrices using triple index notation.

Comment: because each matrix can have a different dimension. Making all the matrices the size of the biggest one and padding with zeros would use too much memory for nothing. Good remark though, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Moreover, the problem with an array stays the same. As soon as the matrix is created, if I modify it (or the vector), the matrix becomes a copy so array and matrix don't share the same values anymore. Somehow, I want to create a matrix by reference (or pointer) in C++ parlance.